# MongoDB multi-instances application with db migration

Tags: .net, mongodb, migration

I'm using MongoDb in my .NET microservice solution with MongoDriver to access. For migration purposes there is https://www.nuget.org/packages/MongoDBMigrations/ in use. Due to fact, that application is a scalable microservice and the migration is triggered during service startup, I am worry about some kind of race conditions. My question is, what will happen in case of simultaneous startup of few instances of service in the same time? I tried to reach some docs about that but without a desirable result. Also tried to simulate such situation locally, but also everything seems to work properly. Regards